# Advantage of using connect over updating foreign keys directly

Tags: prisma

Why use connect?

```
data:{
  'userId': 1
}
```

the above one is not enough??

Why use

```
user:{
 connect:{
    id: 1
  }
}
```

Isn't the result the same? I wonder

Comment: Both should be valid. Are you experiencing issues?

Comment: @some-user I don\`t have a issue but Then why does connect exist? (disconnect also) I\`m confused .  Does it exist because of readability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, why `connect` exists at all:

`connect` (and `disconnect`) provide an alternative interface to relations that you can also achieve by updating the respective fields directly. However, there are many cases, when the API is much more convenient.

E.g.

- updating the object that does not store the attribute that represents the relation
- updating a many-to-many relation
- more advanced interfaces like `connectOrCreate`
- connecting entities on unique attributes other than the primary key